# FORTRAN IntelliSense extension (path) - Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, fortran, vscode-extensions

After installing FORTRAN IntelliSense extension, then when using in a file by Select Language Mode keep getting a popup

[image]
Error spawning fortls: Please check that fortran-language-server is installed and in your path.

So in Settings of VSC go to Extensions > Fortran IntelliSence

[image]

and have this word as path ***fortls*** assumed it would be a environment variable, but doesn't seems to be the case since it doesn't exist one by that name.

In the extension documentation is refered:

Configuration
Note: When setting an explicit language server executable path on Windows backslashes must be escaped (ex. C:\path\to\fortls.exe).

but can't find anywhere this executable so what is the correct path for this extension/executable?

note: the extension is located at **C:\Users\Username\.vscode\extensions\hansec.fortran-ls-0.6.2**

OS: Windows

---

installed in the Visual Studion Extension
[image]

---

In Ctrl+Caps Lock+P Preferences: Configure Languages Specific Settings

"fortran-ls.executablePath": "C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts"

or [image]

created environment variable called fortls that also haves its value that path and added to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: What does "installing FORTRAN IntelliSense extension when using in a file" mean? What exactly did you do? What and how did you exactly install?

Comment: in the Select Language Mode and selected fortran90 that's what i meant in using in a file.

Comment: So, did you actually install the Fortran language server? Like https://github.com/hansec/fortran-language-server Maybe it is available in the Marketplace.

Comment: yes installed in the Visual Studio Code Marketplace in the extensions tab

Comment: OK, extensions, but the language server? Is any of those extensions the language server? The language server and the Intellisense extensions are not the same thing. The latter requires the former.

Comment: ver 0.6.2 of the fortls is very old

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the Fortran language server is actually installed.  (Usually installed via python pip. For example:

```
pip install fortran-language-server
```

For me, it was installed in c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\scripts\fortls.exe

You can verify via running with --version option.

After installing the Fortran Intellisense extension either set the executable path setting to the your install path (c:\bla\bla\fortls) OR, in the settings.json (don't forget to escape backslashes in the .json).  For example:

```
"fortran-ls.executablePath": "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts\\fortls",
```

If you cannot find the fortls.exe, just search for it using windows file explorer.  Assuming you only have one drive, search c:\ and use the following search script:

```
file: fortls.exe
```

It may take a while, but it should show up in the search results.